# php Excel Writer creating unreadable content

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, excel, phpexcel

I am working on a project where we have started moving things to the final server for production. We have not changed the code at all, but the excel export is not working properly. When we open the exported file up it gives the error of "unreadable content". When I click yes to correct it leaves excel blank without even bringing up a blank spreadsheet. Looking at the excel error log I cant seem to find anything to point to the issue.

I've started commenting out code and the file works as soon as I comment out the lines that take data from the server and put them in the excel file. Once again this worked fine on our DEV enviornment but I know they are using different types of servers.

Dev Env - 2008 SQL Server with apache web server 
Prod Env - 2012 SQL Server with apache web server

Below is the code:

```
public function actionchecklistExport( $id )
{
    $mastertracker = TblHarvestMasterTracker::model()->findByPk( $id );
    $model=new TblHarvestExtractionChecklist('search');

    $var_system_family = '';
    if( isset( $mastertracker->attributes['system_family'] ) && !empty( $mastertracker->attributes['system_family'] ) )
    $var_system_family = $mastertracker->attributes['system_family'];

    require_once(Yii::app()->basePath."/extensions/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php");                       


    $workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
    $workbook->setVersion(8); 

    $worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('Extraction Checklist');
    $worksheet->setInputEncoding('UTF-8');        
    //$worksheet->setSheetstate_visible = 'visible';

   // A BUNCH OF CODE TO SETUP LOOK OF SHEET.

    $row_num=0;

    $worksheet->write($row_num,0,"System Tracking #",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,1,"Part Number",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,2,"Description",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,3,"System Model",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,4,"Sub-System",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,5,"Extraction Guidance",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,6,"ICV",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,7,"Specific Extraction",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,8,"Product Locator(N/A/Yes/No)",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,9,"Certified Component(N/A/Yes/No)",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,10,"U Part Set Up Status",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,11,"Part Level Test Document",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,12,"Specific Packaging",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,13,"Captured (Y/N)",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,14,"IF Capture = N",$orangeHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,15,"If Alternate Part or Parent/Child List Part #",$orangeHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,16,"Alternate Part or Parent/Child Action",$orangeHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,17,"Extraction Comments",$orangeHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,18,"Part Level Test Result (Pass, Fail, N/A):",$greenHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,19,"Product Locator Printed(Yes, N/A)",$greenHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,20,"Visual Inspection / Labeling.(Pass, Fail, N/A)",$greenHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,21,"Part Acceptance (Pass, Fail, N/A):",$greenHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,22,"Part Acceptance Initials",$greenHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,23,"Unique ID",$yellowHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,24,"Date",$greenHeader); 
    $worksheet->write($row_num,25,"Disposition if Acceptance Fails",$yellowHeader);  

    $res=$model->search($id, false, false, $var_system_family)->getData();

    $row_num=$row_num+1;
    foreach($res as $key=>$val)
    { 
        //if(!is_null($val['Part_Acceptance_Checklist_Approval_Date']) && $val['Part_Acceptance_Checklist_Approval_Date']!='' && $val['Part_Process_Status']=='Step 3: Awaiting PO')
        //{
        //    $content_text = &$workbook->addFormat( array( 'fgcolor'=> '22','border'=>'1','Size' => '12', 'align'=>'center' ,'FontFamily' => 'GE Inspira') );
        //    $content_text->setTextWrap();        
        //}
        //else
        //{
            //$content_text = &$workbook->addFormat( array( 'border'=>'1','Size' => '12', 'align'=>'center' ,'FontFamily' => 'GE Inspira') );
           // $content_text->setTextWrap();    
        //} 

        //$worksheet->write($row_num,0,$val['variable1'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,1,$val['variable2'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,2,$val['variable3'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,3,$val['variable4'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,4,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,5,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,6,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,7,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,8,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,9,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,10,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,11,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,12,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,13,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,14,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,15,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,16,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,17,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,18,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,19,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,20,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
       // $worksheet->write($row_num,21,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,22,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,23,$val['variable'],$content_text );

        //if( !isset($val['variable'] ) || empty( $val['variable'] ) || $val['variable'] )
        //    $acceptance_date='NULL';
        //else
        //    $acceptance_date=$model->date( Yii::app()->params['php_dateformat_datepicker'], strtotime( $val['variable'] ) );

        //$worksheet->write($row_num,24,$acceptance_date,$content_text ); 
        //$worksheet->write($row_num,25,$val['variable'],$content_text ); 
        $row_num++; 

    } 
    $workbook->send('NTP ' .$id .' SID ' .$sid. ' Extraction Checklist.xls');                   
    $workbook->close();


}
```

As you can see I have the data pull commented out presently (I have "variable" listed in all the spots where various variables are pulled in, and I double checked to make sure the variables are correct. I even tried one by one leaving one of the data pull variables working to see if I could find if it was only one of the items having a hard time.

I have also tried changing the file type to .xslx to no avail.

Is there something specific to the 2012 machine compared to the 2008 that could cause this issue? Or do you see a problem in the code that could be my problem.

Comment: Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer !== PHPExcel

Comment: sorry I meant Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer, I have made the correction